# Skype IM Privacy Settings

Tags: skype, instant-messaging, privacy

I have my skype privacy settings defined to only allow IMs from people in my contact list.  I also have this set for calls/video, etc.  And yet, almost every morning when I boot up I have a conversation request from somebody I do not know.  Shouldn't these settings block these requests?  Is there a way to actually only allow IMs from people in my contact list in skype that works?

Comment: same here, and the most strange thing that i still get strangers, spammers messages :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you should have to do is go to file>options>Privacy> Then choose the options you want

[image]

- http://www.skype.com/security/safety/safety.html
- http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=360781&start=100&p=1766761&#entry1766761

and

Skype does not (and never has) prevented new users from sending requests to exchange contact details -- a feature to prevent such unsolicited approaches has been suggested many times

the privacy settings DO NOT apply to such requests, they apply to calls and IM

yes, a request to exchange details can include a reltively short introductory message and, yes, to a large degree, these messages LOOK like normal IM (especially if you collapse the upper section of the conversation window), but they are not

if your privacy is set to accept IM only from people on your contact list, this new user cannot send you any more regular IM, they cannot call you, they cannot send you files, and they canoot see your profile details or your online status

if they send you another request to exchange details (assuming you haven't blocked them already) they can include more introductory message

yes, if they create a new Skype Name, they can bug you some more, but there is also a way to report such abuse to Skype

that's how it is and how it always has been

(source: http://forum.skype.com/index.php?s=584f1120c3106d873a348ce7b4a12748&showtopic=350191&mode=threaded)

Comment: Hmmm - What I really found interesting about this linked discussion is the sublink which is a situation I have also seen and is even more of a security issue where you accidentally end up adding them to the contact list.   http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=360781&start=100&p=1766761&#entry1766761.   Furthermore it seems to me that friend requests should appear differently in the UI than IMs from accepted users.  And there should be a way to block friend requests.  Aurgh!!!!

Comment: You seem to be saying that just because Skype has **always** been this way, it should stay this way. Skype has recently acquired a number of Windows Live Messenger users, who could depend upon privacy settings which meant what they said. If I say Allow calls from 'my contacts' it means I do NOT want to be bothered by total strangers trying to make my acquaintance. If long-time Skype users are happy with this behaviour, then we need another setting: **Allow no unsolicited contact**. I have been using Windows Live Messenger and its predecessor MSN Messenger for years, without having this problem

Answer (score 2):

This is default behavior with Skype.  Unfortunately if they limit friend requests, they would render the tool unusable for some users.  This is annoying at times, however a some point your contact info will get purged from the spammers lists if you fail to respond.

Comment: The default is to allow calls from everyone. However, they provide settings that imply that you can limit all communications to people on your contact list, if you so choose. The behavior of the app itself seems to violate their own privacy settings.

Comment: So is it better to ignore or to block and report?  It still seems Skype should have an option that allows the user to have the option to completely block these requests.  When using it in a business environment, I am more than happy to only add users manually than through friend requests.  Make it an advanced option, but I think users would appreciate it.  I will have to look for a comments page on their web site.  Comically - submitting to their forum is currently temporarily shut down due to spammers!

Comment: I am not sure why this comment was downvoted.  It is probably accurate even if we do not like it. Voting it back up.